# bcrypt - 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, flask

Tengo este código en python, independientemente de la versión que use de python 2.x o 3.x me lanza el mismo error.

```
def hash_password(password):
    return bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf8'), bcrypt.gensalt())


def credentials_valid(username, password):
    with session_scope() as s:
        user = s.query(User).filter(User.name.in_([username])).first()
        if user:
            return bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf8'), user.password.encode('utf8'))
        else:
            return False
```

Pero cuando intento ejecutar obtengo este error:

```
return bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf8'), user.password.encode('utf8'))
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Comment: password ya es de tipo byes, no str, no tienes que codificarlo..

Comment: Pero si quito el encode, me dice que deberían ser codificados antes de ser verificados

Comment: `user.password` o `password` en `credentials_valid` es ya un objeto bytes (o los dos)... Haz `print(type(password), type( user.password))` antes de la línea  `return bcrypt.checkpw` y muestra que imprime.

Comment: (<type 'unicode'>, <type 'buffer'>)